# Rails how to follow redirect in HTTParty GET request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, httparty

I am using httparty to send a get request and then trying to follow the redirect:

```
get 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth'
```

how can i follow the redirect using HTTParty?

sorry if this have been asked before, but i could not find the answer anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to build you own authentication gem or is this just a random URL you came up with?

Comment: If the example isn't random, you could take a look at the [**omniauth** gem](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth) with [omniauth-google](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) to solve your challenge.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm - It's a random url out of the google api.

Comment: So what do the HTTParty docs say about redirects?

Comment: @ThomasKlemm - I couldn't find anything about the redirect.

Comment: To me it would make sense that an HTTP Client 3xx follows redirects, but you'll find out with testing it then.

Comment: If you care for alternative [HTTP Clients](http://www.plugingeek.com/categories/http-clients-ruby), there are a few out there worth of note.

Answer (score 9):

Probably it's not needed now, but for someone who need.

From [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnunemaker/httparty/HTTParty/ClassMethods#follow_redirects-instance_method), there is special option for automatically redirects

> ## follow_redirects(value = true) ⇒ Object
>
> Proceed to the location header when an HTTP response dictates a redirect. Redirects are always followed by default.

So you can use this options like that:

```
HTTParty.get('http://google.com', follow_redirects: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing this is a little out of date now, what with the question being about a month old... but my understanding of the HTTParty docs is that it should automatically follow redirects, unless you set the no_follow flag.  I haven't successfully tested it though (I'm a total HTTParty n00b and stumbled on this trying to find an answer to my own problem, d'oh...)

If that doesn't work, you could always read the header directly and parse the redirect manually.  I've done that in Javascript AJAX requests before, it is not difficult.  But you shouldn't have to do that with HTTParty.

Comment: I had to actually construct the url and redirect manually, that's the only way it worked.

Comment: It doesn't look like it follows redirects if the response code is `200` and if it uses a `meta` tag redirect instead.